# Laptop crashes on Window Server malloc error

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, apple-silicon

I do see some similar reports on here, but they are old. The symptoms are that I'll be working, it can be saving a doc, or using zoom, or switching windows, and the screen goes black, and eventually I'm asked to login again, assuming a restart has occured. I attached the stack dump report. I'm on an M1 macbook pro 14". More details as required.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               WindowServer [34547]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2022-11-16 16:54:17.4271 +1100
OS Version:            macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F3FF04F0-0117-541E-678A-4CF010D44C3B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5B5932AC-1714-4454-AC1C-B8504B9E9A21

Time Awake Since Boot: 240000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1941 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  ws_main_thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 Crashed:: ws_main_thread Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dabf224 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf5cec pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x19da2f2c8 abort + 180
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib                 0x19d94df18 malloc_vreport + 908
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib                 0x19d9644e4 malloc_zone_error + 100
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib                 0x19d95c2e8 nanov2_guard_corruption_detected + 44
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib                 0x19d95b750 nanov2_allocate_outlined + 388
7   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19d78e5c4 _objc_rootAllocWithZone + 40
8   Metal                                  0x1a6d96c3c +[MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor allocWithZone:] + 80
9   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19d7b49e4 objc_alloc_init + 72
10  Metal                                  0x1a6d96b8c -[MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptorArrayInternal objectAtIndexedSubscript:] + 68
11  SkyLight                               0x1a28fb73c setup_render_pass_descriptor(RenderState&, MTLLoadAction, MTLStoreAction) + 80
12  SkyLight                               0x1a28fbd90 MetalContext::StartCompositeForDisplayStream(id<MTLTexture>, objc_object<MTLTexture>, MTLLoadAction, MTLStoreAction) + 416
13  SkyLight                               0x1a2ad4768 CompositorMetal::ScaleTextureRectToTextureBGRA(CGColorSpace*, CGColorSpace*, CGSRegionObject*, CGRect, id<MTLTexture>, CGRect, objc_object<MTLTexture>, bool, float, float vector[4], bool) + 140
14  SkyLight                               0x1a2ad4370 CompositorMetal::CopySurface(__IOSurface*, CGColorSpace*, CGRect, __IOSurface*, CGColorSpace*, CGRect, CGSRegionObject*, float vector[4]) + 444
15  SkyLight                               0x1a289a9d8 rebuild_one_menu_bar(PKGManagedMenuSpace*, CGSRegionObject**, bool) + 6796
16  SkyLight                               0x1a2898ea0 invocation function for block in rebuild_menu_bars_passing_test(bool (PKGManagedSpace*) block_pointer) + 124
17  SkyLight                               0x1a2984ed4 PKGForEachManagedMenuSpace + 256
18  SkyLight                               0x1a2898c34 rebuild_menu_bars_passing_test(bool (PKGManagedSpace*) block_pointer) + 212
19  SkyLight                               0x1a28a2fc0 rebuild_app_menu_bars(unsigned int, bool) + 132
20  SkyLight                               0x1a28a2d00 set_menu_bars(CGXConnection*, CGSPerMenuBarData const*, unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int, CGSMenuBarFilterType, float vector[4], bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) + 2144
21  SkyLight                               0x1a2b2759c _XSetMenuBars + 224
22  SkyLight                               0x1a28c1f40 invocation function for block in connectionHandler(unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, void*) + 292
23  SkyLight                               0x1a28c1dd0 invocation function for block in connectionHandler(unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, void*) + 112
24  SkyLight                               0x1a2a85634 CGXHandleMessage + 156
25  SkyLight                               0x1a28c1a8c connectionHandler(unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, void*) + 256
26  SkyLight                               0x1a2ae76f0 post_port_data + 280
27  SkyLight                               0x1a2ae7350 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 1396
28  SkyLight                               0x1a2ae7e48 server_loop + 128
29  SkyLight                               0x1a2ae7c94 SLXServer + 1332
30  WindowServer                           0x100ddb3bc 0x100dd8000 + 13244
31  dyld                                   0x19d7cbe50 start + 2544

Thread 1:: com.apple.coreanimation.display.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab6df0 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dac88d8 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dabf638 mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab716c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd5bdc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd44c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd38a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CoreFoundation                         0x19dc5a818 CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   QuartzCore                             0x1a54912dc CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 404
9   QuartzCore                             0x1a525d410 thread_fun(void*) + 32
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf606c _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf0e2c thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: com.apple.coreanimation.frameinfo.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab6df0 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dac88d8 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dabf638 mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab716c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd5bdc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd44c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd38a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CoreFoundation                         0x19dc5a818 CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   QuartzCore                             0x1a5491524 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::frame_info_thread_body(void*) + 404
9   QuartzCore                             0x1a525d410 thread_fun(void*) + 32
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf606c _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf0e2c thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.coreanimation.cursor.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab6df0 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dac88d8 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dabf638 mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19dab716c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd5bdc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd44c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19dbd38a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CoreFoundation                         0x19dc5a818 CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   QuartzCore                             0x1a5492ea4 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::cursor_thread_body(void*) + 440
9   QuartzCore                             0x1a525d410 thread_fun(void*) + 32
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf606c _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19daf0e2c thread_start + 8

...


-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"WindowServer","timestamp":"2022-11-16 16:54:21.00 +1100","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"715a6a48-feb7-324b-a3fb-d5c9e6506d00","build_version":"","platform":1,"share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)","roots_installed":0,"incident_id":"D537F84E-CED0-4113-A14B-647652C443B4","name":"WindowServer"}
{
  "uptime" : 240000,
  "procRole" : "Graphics",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 88,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,3",
  "coalitionID" : 339,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 13.0.1",
    "build" : "22A400",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-11-16 16:54:17.4271 +1100",
  "incident" : "D537F84E-CED0-4113-A14B-647652C443B4",
  "pid" : 34547,
```